# Dynamic navbar with menu items - active class

Tags: laravel

i have navbar with dynamic menu items: Blade:

```
@foreach($main_nav as $page)
   @if($page->visible == 1)
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link @if (Request::is($page->url)) { active } @endif" href="{{ URL::to($page->url) }}">{{ $page->title }}</a>
      </li>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
// MAIN NAVBAR
$view->with('main_nav', Menuitem::where('visible',1)->where('navbar_id', '1')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get());
```

My menuitem's table have fields:

id, url - string (static url or dynamic slug) for example: 'example.com/example', title - string, order - to display elements in order

Now I have question: how to write the condition correctly:

```
@if (Request::is($page->url)) { active } @endif
```

to make active current url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `/*` wild-card for this:

```
Request::is($page->url . '/*')
```

In your case, you'd have to check for the root, or the dynamic one. Also, you can simplify your code using inline ternary instead of `@if` and `@endif`:

```
<a class="nav-link {{ request()->is($page->url) || request()->is($page->url .'/*') ? 'active' : '' }}"></a>
```

This would match the For the URLs `example.com` and `example.com/example`